# Is it possible to know the date/time of files in asset folder in android?

Tags: android, assets

Before updating/copying files i need to know if files in asset folder are more recent.
I've tried this 'http://myossdevblog.blogspot.fr/2010/02/reading-properties-files-on-android.html', but no date/time information.

How can i do this?

Comment: Maybe you can keep track of file date/time in a separate text file inside the assets....

Comment: The timestamp in the APK package is just the timestamp when the APK was built; not the asset file original timestamp. Consider some other versioning approach for your problem.

Comment: @laalto its working if files are in  data/data/com.example.pkg/files path of DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about asset folder but it is possible if your files are in **data/data/com.example.pkg/files** path of your DDMS perspective.

Use  `public long lastModified ()`

It returns the time when this file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since **January 1st, 1970, midnight**. Returns 0 if the file does not exist.

Returns     **the time when this file was last modified.**

```
 File[] files = dir.listFiles();//dir.listFiles() refers to data/data/com.example.pkg/files  path of your DDMS
   for (File f : files ) {

       // Get the last modified date. Miliseconds since 1970
       Long lastmodified = f.lastModified();

       Log.i("return value of file.lastModified()", new Date(lastmodified).toString());
       }
```

Comment: It's not workikng, i've all the time :`Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970`, My file is directly in the asset folder, so i've change th epath : `Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/LSPCC2.db")`;

Comment: if your file is in directly asser folder then use this `"file:///android_asset/abc.txt"`

Comment: try to use any other files except .db and check log

Comment: my file is LSPCC2.db, directly in the asset folder. I've already change the path, ;(

Comment: Note that your last modified is zero and all you did is to format it to your local timezone (UTC+05:30).

Comment: @morbak  its working if files are in data/data/com.example.pkg/files path of DDMS. Check my edits

Comment: if i execute this code, i can read inside the instr.txt in the aseets folder, so files exist.`InputStream is = getAssets().open("instr.txt");
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                  String line = null;
                  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      Log.e("wtf", line);
                  }
                  br.close();`

Comment: if you put files in `data/data/com.example.pkg/files` path of DDMS then my edited code will work.